# Structure the network file share folder/data

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, network-drive

Network file share folders/datas are unstructured/ collapsed/ No tree structure with archived/unwanted datas/folders. We want the approaches to structure the data using Department wise/ Tasks/ Group.

Our ultimate goal is to migrate file share datas/folders to sharepoint/onedrive.

Answer (score 0):

File Share structure is not much of a SharePoint scope question. It is simply based on how users perform sharing in your organization.

You can use SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) and follow the Official guide to complete the process. Choose what you want to migrate and leave the unwanted data behind.

Reference:

[File share to OneDrive and SharePoint Migration Guide.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/fileshare-to-odsp-migration-guide)

Another reference for suggestions on how to prepare for migration from File Share to SharePoint Online.

[Preparing for a File Share to SharePoint Migration.](https://sharegate.com/blog/prepare-file-share-migration-to-sharepoint)

Comment: We want to structure and skip unwanted/archived folders/documents. Once we have structure/hierarchy in the SP or Onedrive, Business operations could be easily done by users.

Comment: @KarthikeyanGanesan I understand your need, but I don’t think there is a tool that can automatic this process for you, neither SPMT nor 3rd party tool. In fact, migration to SharePoint/OneDrive gives you the opportunity to organize and clean up unused content. Check ShareGate and see if you can get help from it.

Comment: We have this approach now, We can set up other shared folder department/ Tasks/ Group wise to structure/hierarchy the folder/data. Once we have the hierarchy, ask the user to move/copy their folder/documents to new shared folder. Once done from the user end, we start the migration to SP/Onedrive. This is what we plan now. I want to know if any other better approaches to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have hierarchy you can copy folder/documents to new folder in SPO library. You can you use SharePoint Migration Tool(SPMT) by Microsoft and it is free.
[image]

You can choose following option
1. File Share: if you want same folder structure from Source to destination. using this you can only give source location and destination library in SPO.
2. JSON or CSV: if you want to copy source file/folder to different destination folder

Sample JSON:

```
{   "Tasks": [
    {
      "SourcePath": "C:\\Users\\Sample",
      "TargetPath": "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/samplesite",
      "TargetList": "Documents",
      "TargetListRelativePath": "Folder1/SubFolder1"
    }   ] }
```

Comment: I think you mentioned the migration part. But here what we need is to structure/hierarchy the data/documents approaches.